# How to exclude current item from related item search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a post view where I want to display related posts but what I have now **includes** the current post as well.

How would I go about removing the current item from the search?

I don't know how to use `where.not()` or `!=` in this situation or if they're even the best thing to use.

This is what I have in my **post show view**:

```
<% @related[@post.blog_category_id]&.each do |rel| %>
  <a href="/posts/<%= rel.friendly_id %>" class="img-cont">
    <%= image_tag("Index/#{rel.thumbnail_link}", :alt => "#{rel.title}", class: "soundtrack-img top-drop") %>
    <div class="img-mdl wellington"><h3 class="img-txt basic"><%= rel.title %></h3></div>
  </a>
<% end %>
```

And in my **posts_controller** show method:

`@related = Post.friendly.all.group_by(&:blog_category_id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@related` already includes all posts, you need to remove the current post from the list or skip it in the iteration:

Exclude the current one before iterating

```
<% @related[@post.blog_category_id].reject { |post| post == @post }&.each do |rel| %>
```

*or* just skip the iteration if the current one is the post in question:

```
<% @related[@post.blog_category_id]&.each do |rel| %>
  <% next if rel == @post %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.offset(1)`. Something like:

`@related = Post.friendly.all.group_by(&:blog_category_id).offset(1)`

or

`@related = Post.friendly.all.group_by(&:blog_category_id).order("created_at desc").offset(1)`